# hash index vs elastic search

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, hash

I'm new with MySQL and elasticsearch. I have been confused betweeen something called hash index versus elasticsearch. For example, if I have an "user" table, how can I find an user from specified email? I have thought about 2 resolution.
1. Using hash index: created new column like "email_hash" and create a hash index on this column and query base on this new column.
2. Just using elasticsearch.

I have been confused what resolution I should use? Or can I take both of them for better query performance? Any help is very appreciate. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic search internally is an index but with lot more capabilities. If you just want a simple search where in you send the email and get the user back then just go with mysql. If you have much more requirements like find words in singular/plural forms or stemmed words. Its advised to use elastic search.